# Manipulating two or more arrays into one array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am getting this set of array from my server:

{
"tableName": [
"adconfig",
"api_info",
"dbconfig",
"dialog_flow",
"employees",
"ldap_details",
"license_details",
"login_details",
"maggie_user",
"mailconfig",
"role_management",
"server_details",
"ticketingtool",
"use_case_details",
"user_tbl",
"people"
],
"creation": [
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30",
"2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30"
],
"modifyDate": [
"2021-12-30 12:52:59+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-30 10:42:58+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30",
"2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30",
"2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30"
] }

I want to achieve this:

[0: {tableName:"adconfig",creation: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30",modifyDate:"2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30"},

1: {tableName:"api_info",creation: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30",modifyDate:"2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30"},

2: {tableName:"dbconfig",creation: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30",modifyDate:"2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30"},

and so on........]

I tried creating 3 arrays as:

tableName: Array(15) 0: "adconfig" 1: "api_info" 2: "dbconfig" 3: "dialog_flow" 4: "employees" 5: "ldap_details" 6: "license_details" 7: "login_details" 8: "maggie_user" 9: "mailconfig" 10: "role_management" 11: "server_details" 12: "ticketingtool" 13: "use_case_details" 14: "user_tbl"

creation: Array(15) 0: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 1: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 2: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 3: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 4: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 5: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 6: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 7: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 8: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 9: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 10: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 11: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" 12: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" 13: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" 14: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30"

modify Date: Array(15) 0: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 1: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 2: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 3: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 4: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 5: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 6: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 7: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 8: "2022-01-05 11:33:18+05:30" 9: "2022-01-05 11:28:33+05:30" 10: "2022-01-05 11:33:18+05:30" 11: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" 12: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" 13: "2022-01-05 11:33:19+05:30" 14: "2022-01-05 11:28:34+05:30" length: 15

Then i tried to join this three to get what i desired but was not able to, I would really appreciate if someone comes with any solution. Sorry for the formatting issue as i am quite new here so please pardon me Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

So 3 arrays inside an object, and you want to `zip` them; Each item is at same index across arrays, and all three arrays have the same length.

```js
const zipped = []

for(const i=0; i<response.tableName.length; i++) {
  zipped.push({
    tableName: response.tableName[i],
    creation: response.creation[i],
    modifyDate: response.modifyDate[i],
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the correct results.

```js
const serverData = { 
  "tableName": [ "adconfig", "api_info", "dbconfig", "dialog_flow", "employees", "ldap_details", "license_details", "login_details", "maggie_user", "mailconfig", "role_management", "server_details", "ticketingtool", "use_case_details", "user_tbl", "people" ],
  "creation": [ "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30" ],
  "modifyDate": [ "2021-12-30 12:52:59+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:42:58+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30" ] 
};

const listLen = serverData["tableName"].length;
const results = [...Array(listLen)].map((_, i) => ({
    tableName: serverData.tableName[i],
    creation: serverData.creation[i],
    modifyDate: serverData.modifyDate[i]
}));

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the lengths of each array is same and "response" is received from server, here is a one liner solution:-

```
let result = response.tableName.map((name,i) => {
    return {name, response.creation[i], response.modifyDate[i]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` on one of array and combine from other arrays based on index

```js
const data = { 
  "tableName": [ "adconfig", "api_info", "dbconfig", "dialog_flow", "employees", "ldap_details", "license_details", "login_details", "maggie_user", "mailconfig", "role_management", "server_details", "ticketingtool", "use_case_details", "user_tbl", "people" ],
  "creation": [ "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30" ],
  "modifyDate": [ "2021-12-30 12:52:59+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:42:58+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:52+05:30", "2021-12-29 18:11:53+05:30", "2021-12-30 10:28:59+05:30" ] 
};

const { tableName, creation, modifyDate } = data;
const output = tableName.map((tableName, i) => ({
  tableName,
  creation: creation[i],
  modifyDate: modifyDate[i]
}))

console.log(output);
```